# Upper bound on Taylor's series expansion of the exponential

Tags: taylor-expansion

I want a function $a:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$e^{x}\leq 1 + x + a(\epsilon) \frac{x^2}{2}\mbox{ for } |x|\leq \epsilon.$$

Is there a good choice such that $a(\epsilon)\to 1$ as $\epsilon\to 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact function $a$ is convex, then you can take the chord

$$a(x)=\frac{h(\epsilon)-h(-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}(x+\epsilon)+h(-\epsilon),$$

where

$$h(x):=2\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}.$$